# HMR for Local Vue.js App Over HTTPS Setup Shows Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: vue.js, reverse-proxy, webpack-hmr, caddy, caddyfile

#### 1. My Caddy version (`caddy -version`):

`v2.0.0-beta.13 h1:QL0JAepFvLVtOatABqniuDRQ4HmtvWuuSWZW24qVVtk=`

#### 2. How I run Caddy:

a. System environment:

I am using caddy server static binary on `macOS Mojave - 10.14.6`, and make the binary available as `caddy` command in `$PATH`.

b. Command:

```
caddy
```

d. My complete Caddyfile:

```
backend.cdy.test {
  tls ./_wildcard.cdy.test.pem ./_wildcard.cdy.test-key.pem

  reverse_proxy localhost:3000 {
    header_up Host {host}
    header_up Origin {host}
    header_up X-Real-IP {remote}
    header_up X-Forwarded-Host {host}
    header_up X-Forwarded-Server {host}
    header_up X-Forwarded-Port {port}
    header_up X-Forwarded-For {remote}
    header_up X-Forwarded-Proto {scheme}

    header_down Access-Control-Allow-Origin https://frontend.cdy.test
  }

}

frontend.cdy.test {
  tls ./_wildcard.cdy.test.pem ./_wildcard.cdy.test-key.pem

  reverse_proxy localhost:8080 {
    header_up Host "localhost"
    header_up X-Real-IP {remote}
    header_up X-Forwarded-Host "localhost"
    header_up X-Forwarded-Server "localhost"
    header_up X-Forwarded-Port {port}
    header_up X-Forwarded-For {remote}
    header_up X-Forwarded-Proto {scheme}
  }
}
```

#### 3. The problem I'm having:

For first time, I am trying to setup caddy server to run two apps each will run under subdomain of a main domain over HTTPS. One of them is express.js based backend, the other is Vue.js based frontend.

It seems everything works so far, but the **Sockets and Hot Module Replacement** built by Vue.js while development cannot work well.

#### 4. Error messages and/or full log output:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://192.168.5.10:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1888826474028. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost/sockjs-node/info?t=4740717588882. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

#### 5. What I already tried:

There is no concrete trying I can share, but tried to apply what is mentioned in *VueJS dev serve with reverse proxy* article, but I cannot make it work.

```
#localhost {
#  reverse_proxy /sockjs-node localhost {
#    header_up Host "localhost"
#    header_up Origin "localhost"
#    header_up -Access-Control-Allow-Origin
#    header_up Access-Control-Allow-Origin https://frontend.cdy.test
#    header_up Connection {>Connection}
#    header_up Upgrade {>Upgrade}
#
#    header_down Access-Control-Allow-Origin https://frontend.cdy.test
#  }
#}
```

I would like if someone help me to make this local development works fully supported by caddy server as reverse proxy over HTTPS, and if I have any incorrect settings in that Caddyfile, please correct me as I don't have enough knowledge in what is written so far, just tried to apply old directive "transparent" and make settings work same as mentioned in below article.

#### 6. Links to relevant resources:

- [VueJS dev serve with reverse proxy](https://medium.com/js-dojo/vuejs-dev-serve-with-reverse-proxy-e15c776286b8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution.

I had to change the `public` of `devServer` entry in `vue.config.js` file

```js
// vue.config.js file

module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: ['vuetify'],
  devServer: {
    public: 'https://frontend.cdy.test',
    allowedHosts: ['.cdy.test']
  }
}
```

When I run dev server for the Vue application

```
$ npm run serve

  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/ 
  - Network: https://frontend.cdy.test/ <== This used to be http://192.168.5.13
```

I now access `https://frontend.cdy.test/` from the browser and don't see those CORS errors anymore.